# generate JS object string but not JSON

Tags: javascript, json

i have a json object as follow:

```
obj = {
  a : 123,
  b : 456,
  c : 678,
  d : "abcd",
}
```

i want to create a stringified version of this object, but not the `JSON.stringify` result. the `JSON.stringify` result is like this:

```
{
  "a" : 123,
  "b" : 456,
  "c" : 678,
  "d" : "abcd",
}
```

but i want it to be like this:

```
{
  a : 123,
  b : 456,
  c : 678,
  d : "abcd",
}
```

or maybe even:

```
{
  a : 123,
  b : 456,
  c : 678,
  d : 'abcd',
}
```

can just ignore functions, the reason for this is because i want to generate some sample data for fixture but the eslint will make noise due to the double quotes and the key being quoted unnecessarily. the string resulted from this will be written to a file using `fs.writeFileSync`

Answer (score 1):

One limited option would be to search for the `"word":` pattern in the `JSON.stringify`ed string and replace it with only the word characters and colon, omitting the quotes:

```js
const customStringify = obj => JSON.stringify(obj)
  .replace(/"(\w+)":/g, '$1:');

const obj = {
  a : 123,
  b : 456,
  c : 678,
  d : "abcd",
};
console.log(
  customStringify(obj)
);
```

A more flexible way would be to create your own recursive stringifying function:

```js
const customStringify = obj => {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    return '[' + obj
      .map(customStringify)
      .join(',')
      + ']';
  }
  if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    // Plain object:
    return '{' + Object.entries(obj)
      .map(([key, val]) => key + ':' + customStringify(val))
      .join(',')
      + '}';
  }
  // Primitive value:
  return JSON.stringify(obj);
};

const obj = {
  a : 123,
  b : 456,
  c : 678,
  d : "abcd",
  e: [ { foo: 'bar', arr: ['baz', 4, 'buzz'] }]
};
console.log(
  customStringify(obj)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

That can be easily implemented using `reduce` and some ES6 features.

```js
let obj = {
  a : 123,
  b : 456,
  c : 678,
  d : "abcd",
};

function objToString(obj) {

  return '{ \n' + Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc,key) => {
     return `${acc} ${key} : ${obj[key]}, \n`;
  }, '') + '}';

}

console.log(objToString(obj));
```